# Exception: /tmp/ghc3910_0: createDirectory: permission denied (Read-only file system)

Tags: haskell

Ok I'm looking at haskell, why on earth when I do a loading:

```
ghci> :l file.hs
```

the prompt gives me `Exception: /tmp/ghc3910_0: createDirectory: permission denied (Read-only file system)`???

(totally haskell unexperienced)

Comment: What OS?  Try `touch /tmp/aFile` from the command line and tell us what happens.  Also, try `ls -l /tmp/ghc3910_0` and tell us what you see.

Comment: Alright I am in Linux 3.8.0-34-generic #49~precise1-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux. I don't know what happened but today it worked. Very strange. I'll let you know if I have another trouble. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me setting `TMPDIR` explicitly worked:

```
mkdir $HOME/.tmp
export TMPDIR=$HOME/.tmp
```